# How i can build only one JAR-File which is containing several different application/subprojects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just want to create several Spring-Boot applications. But I want to create them all in the same project in parallel. At the end, when I'm building all the stuff via maven just one jar-file should be created. One Jar file which is including all applications.

(Optional: not sure if that is even possible) Each project should have its own pom file and artifact id.

To start a particular application of this one jar file, I want to add some profiles (or something similar, special parameter) so that I can simply start a subproject by given parameter or profile.

I just started with the answer i already got. Made the subprojects, but here every subproject is created in an own jar file. That is exactly not what i want ;).

You have an idea?

Tanks a lot in advance.

ps: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

For this you can build different individual spring-boot project and accumulate all project into one parent project. Then, you can use your every project individually also can use as a parent jar file.

For more details [multi-module-maven](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/sb-multi-module-maven-project/)   [spring-boot-multiple-modules](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-multiple-modules)

Comment: The subprojects looking good to me. But each subproject creates their own jar file. I want, that only one jar for whole project is the result, and just with given parameter or profile, i can start the different subprojects.